# Suitable design for a database application

Tags: php, database, web-applications

I have a question related to a web app that I developed in PHP, MYSQL.

basically part 1 is : 
I display results in the form of table say for software testing.

```
ID Prod_Name       Set    Date      Result  Platform
1  Alpha1          Pro1   01.01.01  PASS    2.3.1.2_OS
```

Now, I have divided the tables accordingly

```
Table Name: Results
ID, Name, Date, Result

Table Name : Set
ID, Set_Name, Prod_name

Table Name : Platform
ID,  Platform_Name, Set_Name
```

Now, ID in each table is an incremented value and does not relate to anything else.

My php app, starts with fetching the results from 'Results' table.  Since I want SET to be displayed for every row, I am making an another connection to the database and using the query

```
select Set_name 
from Set 
where Prod_name = row['Name'] // row['Name'] is fetched from the results table.
```

now I also want to display platform which I am extracting it from Platform table using the above method i.e making another connection and passing `Set_Name = row['Set_Name']` from the Set table.

Now for my application is there any other way to achieve the same result ?

Typically, for large web based applications, if data is coming from a database server is making multiple connection to a DB server a feasible option?

Please do not consider the fact that with MySQL declaring  a connection statement once will do the needful but what about MSSQL server? Do we need to write a long sql statement with several joins/selfjoins/unions and use those variables all over the application?

How is the application design for this case will be?

Can anyonce give me some ideas please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not have understood everything, but here is something similar. First, let's make an ER model.

[image: producttest_model_01]

Now, because you don't seem to like joins, create a view in the database.

```
CREATE VIEW v_test AS
 SELECT TestID, ProductName, TestName, Date, Result, PlatformName
 FROM Product AS p
      JOIN Test AS t ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID
      JOIN Platform AS f ON f.PlatformID = t.PlatformID;
```

With this in place, you can simply use:

```
SELECT * FROM v_test WHERE ProductName = 'Alpha1'
```

You may also take a look at **[this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777420/database-design-how-do-i-track-information-over-time-and-query-a-table-for-late/1801148#1801148)** with a similar scenario.

Answer (score 2):

For pretty much any flavour of database, a single SELECT statement which joins three tables will perform better than three separate statements querying a table apiece.  Joining is what relational databases do.